# How to read text file on AWS Lambda environment

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I am trying to read and store the values of a text file in a variable so that I can covert that text file into CSV file afterwards. But I am getting this error that the file is not found. I used the exact path by right clicking on the text file and select copy path. Still getting this error. Any idea on how to fix this
[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yKzd.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yKzd.jpg) [image: This is the error]

Here is the Code

```
import pandas as pd 
import csv 
import json


dataframe1 = pd.read_csv(r'/data.txt', sep="|")

# storing this dataframe in a csv file
dataframe1.to_csv('CSV_CONVERTED.csv', 
                  index = None)


def csv_to_json(event=None, context=None ):
    jsonArray = []
    csvFilePath = r'/CSV_CONVERTED.csv'
    jsonFilePath = r'/data.json'
      
    #read the csv file
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
        #load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 

        #convert each csv row into python dict
        for row in csvReader: 
            #add this python dict to json array
            jsonArray.append(row)
  
    #convert python jsonArray to JSON String and write to file
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)
    
    return{
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': 'Success'
    }

print(csv_to_json())
```

Here is the error response

> {   "errorMessage": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/data.txt'",   "errorType": "FileNotFoundError",   "stackTrace": [
> "  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n",
> "  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source\n    module = _load(spec)\n",
> "  File "", line 702, in _load\n",
> "  File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked\n",
> "  File "", line 843, in exec_module\n",
> "  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
> "  File "/var/task/Convert.py", line 6, in \n    dataframe1 = pd.read_csv(r'/data.txt', sep="|")\n",
> "  File "/opt/python/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 211, in wrapper\n    return func(*args, **kwargs)\n",
> "  File "/opt/python/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 331, in wrapper\n    return func(*args, **kwargs)\n",
> "  File "/opt/python/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 950, in read_csv\n    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)\n",
> "  File "/opt/python/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 605, in _read\n    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)\n",
> "  File "/opt/python/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1442, in **init**\n    self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)\n",
> "  File "/opt/python/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1735, in _make_engine\n    self.handles = get_handle(\n",
> "  File "/opt/python/pandas/io/common.py", line 856, in get_handle\n    handle = open(\n"   ] }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lambda, you can only write to /tmp/ directory.
The Lambda deployment package is deployed onto /var/task/ directory.

Hence use /tmp/ directory to write your files to.

```py
data_file_path = f"/var/task/data.txt"
csvFilePath = f"/tmp/CSV_CONVERTED.csv"

dataframe1 = pd.read_csv(data_file_path, sep="|")

# storing this dataframe in a csv file
dataframe1.to_csv(csvFilePath, index = None)


def csv_to_json(event=None, context=None ):
    jsonArray = []
    jsonFilePath = f"/tmp/data.json"
      
    #read the csv file
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
        #load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 

        #convert each csv row into python dict
        for row in csvReader: 
            #add this python dict to json array
            jsonArray.append(row)
  
    #convert python jsonArray to JSON String and write to file
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)
    
    return{
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': 'Success'
    }

print(csv_to_json())
```